# How to convert date string into numbers

Tags: python, pandas, replace, find, python-re

I have as input:

```
["3 years 8 months", "10 months", "1 year 10 months", "9 months", " 1 month ", "1 year", "3 years"]
```

I want this output:

```
[3.8, 0.10, 1.10, 0.09, 0.01, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.split`:

```
def to_num(s):
   c = {'year':1, 'years':1, 'month':0.01, 'months':0.01}
   return sum(int(s[i])*c[s[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))

vals = ["3 years 8 months", "10 months", "1 year 10 months", "9 months", "1 month", "1 year", "3 years"]
result = [to_num(i.split()) for i in vals]
```

Output:

```
[3.08, 0.1, 1.1, 0.09, 0.01, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: use `re.search`**

```
import re
def date_to_number(x):
    year, month = 0, 0
    if re.search(r'(\d*)\syear', x):
        year = float(re.search(r'(\d*)\syear', x).group(1))
    if re.search(r'(\d*)\smonth', x):
        month = float(re.search(r'(\d*)\smonth', x).group(1))/100
    return year+month

numbers = [date_to_number(i) for i in data]
```

Output:

```
print(numbers)

[3.08, 0.1, 1.1, 0.09, 0.01, 1.0, 3.0]
```

**Method 2: use `extract()` in Pandas** 

If your data is stored in a dataframe, you can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date'])
df['date_to_number'] = (df['date'].str.extract(r'(\d*)\syear').fillna(0).astype('int') 
                        + df['date'].str.extract(r'(\d*)\smonth').fillna(0).astype('int').divide(100))
```

Output:
print(df)

```
               date  date_to_number
0  3 years 8 months            3.08
1         10 months            0.10
2  1 year 10 months            1.10
3          9 months            0.09
4          1 month             0.01
5            1 year            1.00
6           3 years            3.00
```